# Hive load csv with commas and timestamp

Tags: csv, hive, timestamp, amazon-athena

I Try to load csv file into a Hive. The problem that I have datetime column and column that contains commas. The separators are aslo commas.

```
CMBk7Y,HM - PEUVP,promo,11066,FRA,1401445,Asegment_DLBD,1,imp,2017-05-31 22:52:30,"U=dsp=mmh,bid=0000002,adv=189,cpg=3449,str=2117,cre=41836,exc=apn,pub=3296,sit=leboncoin.fr,pag=https%3A//www.leboncoin.fr/materiel_agricoles/%3Fth%3D1%2ot%3D0;ord=909215572"
```

I can't use open CSVSerDe as I need the date column in datetime format. And CSVSerDe works only with string

I tried to use `ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 "separatorChar" = ",",
"quoteChar" = "\""
)`

But it puts everything in one column.

I've also tried like this: `ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ','`)

In this case it takes everything before the first comma in the last column.

I think that the solution is not far, but I can't find it.

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the RegEx SerDe if you can write a RegEx for that format...that matches on any comma not between quotes.

org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe

Good Luck!!!